# Transparently redirect a domain to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have set up the DNS Zone of my domain towards the IP of my VPS.

When I type `exemple.com` I reach the `httpdocs folder` (the root folder) of the vhost wanted.

However in this folder there are few dirctories

```
httpdocs
-subfolder1
  -Ssub-folder
-subfolder2
```

I would like :

1) that any request directed toward `exemple.com` be redirected toward `exemple.com/subfolder1/` or idealy `exemple.com/subfolder1/Ssubfolder/`

2) and that the url displayed remains `exemple.com`

3) moreover, I also want to be able to acces to `subfolder2` while typing `exemple.com/subfolder2` or while `typing my-IP-adresse/subfolder2`

I made myself sure that the `apache2.conf` file contains `AllowOverride All`, and tried to edit the `.htaccess` file located in the `httpdocs folder` in many many ways, for instance :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exemple\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exemple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /subfolder1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^subfolder1($|/) http://exemple.com/subfolder1/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both redirect me correctly, but the url displayed is `exemple.com/subfolder/`

I've also tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://exemple.com/subfolder/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

But my url becomes `http://exemple.com/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/`

When I try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder1/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exemple\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

the server replies `file not found`

Finally I've tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exemple.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exemple.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder1/index.php [L]
```

but no redirection occurs

With more and more tries, I get similar results, but never the one aimed.

Any help would be awesome

Thank's in advance

ps: I'm on ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and apache 2.4.7

Comment: Why don't you simply setup two separate virtual hosts for the two domains?

Comment: hi, thank's, actually the subfoler1 contains a cms handling multisites and the Ssubfolder the site itself (I only have one), the subfolder2 contain OTX, an app that convert .odt files into XML-TEI files. The CMS can use OTX to facilitate the import of content but there is quite a lot of user right and relative/absolute path issues and such, so keeping them in the same vhost was the only way to make it work for me (and this is how the dev of the cms suggest to do)